# OpenBSD install from CD does not find installation file set

Tags: installation, openbsd

We are installing OpenBSD on one of our machines. After configuring the hostname and directories, there's an error on installing the sets

I'm installing from a CD, but the system does not recognize the files on the CD on either:

4.1/i386 (INSTALL.i386 not found)

/ (No OpenBSD/i386 4.1 sets were found)

Used this as a guide:
https://bowerstudios.com/node/91

Comment: Do not install a version of BSD *that old*. You're asking for problems of all sorts.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to install a version of OpenBSD that is five and a half years old.

Starting with OpenBSD 4.2, an installation ISO is part of the release and there is no need to create your own.

See http://www.openbsd.org/faq/faq4.html for instructions on installing OpenBSD from CDROM.

Answer (score 0):

I got here searching for how to file the file sets from usb during OpenBSD install.

I had reached `Pathname to the sets?` prompt and the USB stick was not mounted.

Based on [this great post](https://teddit.net/r/openbsd/comments/9xitpz/need_help_with_usb_install/e9uld2t/#c):

1. Exit the installer; type `!`
2. Identify USB device name; remove the usb and re-insert. Find the `sdx` name, e.g. `sd4`.
3. `cd /dev`
4. `MAKEDEV sdx` (e.g. `sd4` from step 2)
5. `mkdir /usb`
6. `mount /dev/sdxa /usb` (e.g. `sd4a` from step 2)
7. `exit` (returns to OpenBSD installer)
8. `/usb/7.3/amd64` (at `Pathname to the sets?` prompt. Note may be different dependent on OpenBSD version and target architecture; exit installer and check `/usb` dir if unsure)